# Sorting dictionary of lists ranked such that the item for which the ith index of the value list is largest

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

Working in python 3 i've got the following problem:

My dictionary consists of units (keys) and lists of activity (values), I have to sort it such that is is ranked by peak activity. Meaning that I want to find per index i, the dict item for which this ith value is the highest value in the list of values.

```
example_dict = {unit1: [1, 4, 3], unit2: [2, 2, 2], unit3:  [1, 1, 1]}

sorted_dict  = {unit2: [2, 2, 2], unit1: [1, 4, 3], unit3:  [1, 1, 1]}
```

I fear it might be the case that there is not per se an optimal solution in which case i'm happy with an arbitrary choice of solution.

Comment: hopefully the example i gave helps!

Comment: I thought I understood the question, but now that you've added your example I realized that I have no idea how that output is generated.

Comment: Do you mean you dont understand what i want? Or you don't know the solution?

Comment: I'm saying I don't understand the question. The output looks like you want to sort the dict keys by their values, but in your question you're talking about finding the maximum for each index.

Comment: so in this example unit2 is ranked on top, because since all values are 2, the first value:2 is also the highest value. Then because on the second position unit1 has its highest value there (4>1,3) this item gets place two. I suppose one could argue unit3 might as well go there (since 1 is the highest value of unit3) , but I would prefer unit2 to be placed second as 4>1.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now. But you should really [edit] that explanation into the question to get rid of those close votes that are piling up.

Comment: What type of object are `unit1`, `unit2`, and `unit3`?  Or are they supposed to be literal strings?

Comment: `OrderedDict([('unit3', [1, 1, 1]), ('unit1', [1, 4, 3]), ('unit2', [2, 2, 2])])` is also a valid result, right?

Comment: The only problem I can see in what you're trying to do is when a *tie* happens.. There are plenty of cases where no solution will be available

Comment: Dictionaries aren't meant to be sorted or in any particular order, I suggest you look for a more pythonic way of doing things.

Comment: @Aran-Fey yes that is also a good solution!

Comment: @PM 2Ring they are actually integers, but i thought that would be distracting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For each list, find the index of the maximum element
2. Group the lists by that index
3. Pick an arbitrary element from each group and put it into the result at the correct index
4. Use the remaining elements to fill the empty slots in the result

```
import operator
import collections

example_dict = {'unit1': [1, 4, 3],
                'unit2': [2, 2, 2],
                'unit3': [1, 1, 1]}

# group the lists by the index of their maximum element
lists_by_max_index = collections.defaultdict(list)

for key, values in example_dict.items():
    # find the index of the maximum element
    max_index, max_value = max(enumerate(values), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    # and store the key in the corresponding group
    lists_by_max_index[max_index].append(key)

# list_by_max_index is now {1: ['unit1'], 0: ['unit2', 'unit3']}

# make a list representing the sorted dict and initialize it to None
sorted_keys = [None] * len(next(iter(example_dict.values())))
unused_keys = []

# sorted_keys is [None, None, None]

# for each group in the dict we created earlier, put a random key into
# the list
for i, keys in lists_by_max_index.items():
    sorted_keys[i] = keys.pop()
    unused_keys += keys  # store the other keys for later

# sorted_keys is now ['unit3', 'unit1', None]

# iterate over the list and fill any empty slots with arbitrary unused keys
for i, key in enumerate(sorted_keys):
    if key is None:
        sorted_keys[i] = unused_keys.pop()

# sorted_keys is now ['unit3', 'unit1', 'unit2']

# finally, grab the corresponding value for each key and turn the whole thing
# into an OrderedDict
sorted_dict = [(key, example_dict[key]) for key in sorted_keys]
sorted_dict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted_dict)

print(sorted_dict)
# output:
# OrderedDict([('unit3', [1, 1, 1]),
#              ('unit1', [1, 4, 3]),
#              ('unit2', [2, 2, 2])])
```

Useful functions and classes I used:

- [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for grouping
- [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to store the result
- [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as a key function for [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)
- [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) and [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to get an arbitrary element from a dict

Comment: Thank you so much! I believe it works exactly as needed!